# gdb debugging oddity

Tags: c++, gdb

When using gdb for debugging some code,it sometimes repeats some code fragments several times while using next command, after this repeat, with the n command, it continues sequentially over program lines normally. What is the reason of this strange behaviour? Or anyone had this problem before? What could be the fix for this? I have GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2-ubuntu.

Comment: A log showing this behavior would be nice, cannot reproduce...

Comment: not clear what you want from me but most of the time this happens when I try to step into templates, and optimization could be another source...

Answer (score 4):

Program may have been compiled using optimizations. Try again with -O0 when compiling.

Comment: +1 is that the only reason, I mean to turn on optimisation flags